# How to export a plot into a file?

Tags: graphics, export

I am trying to save some graphics into a file, and it seems impossible.

```
x1 = Round[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[325, 5], 25], 0.1];
x2 = Round[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[325.5, 2], 25], 0.1];
x3 = Round[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[327.5, 7], 25], 0.1];

h1 = Histogram[x1, 6, "Probability", 
   ChartLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)"}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Directive[Red]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{308, 342}, {0, 0.5}}];
h2 = Histogram[x2, 6, "Probability", 
   ChartLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Directive[Blue]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{308, 342}, {0, 0.5}}];
h3 = Histogram[x3, 6, "Probability", 
   ChartLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)"}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Directive[Green]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{308, 342}, {0, 0.5}}];
   Export["C:\CompareHist.png", GraphicsColumn[{h1, h2, h3}]]
```

Of course I cannot use save graphics into file option as there is no such option.
And by the way: why Export functions always fails? Even when trying to follow [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html?q=Export&lang=en). Is it some known bug?

Comment: Have you tried with "\\" rather than "\" in your file name ?

Comment: When no C:\ it works. But how to write paths then?

Comment: Have a look at `FileNameJoin`.

Comment: I am, but you first gave me the right solution, and I wanted to vote your answer.

Comment: Lol, why my post was downvoted?

Comment: The reason why the single backslash fails as a path separator is that the backslah acts as escape character in strings as in many programming languages. "\t", for instance, codes for the tab character. This means that if you want to have the literal backslash you need to escape that with the escape character, which is the backslash itself. So "\\" is the `\\` character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, outputting into the desktop is quite handy. Thus, in every notebook I have one initialization cell that selects the output folder

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\R\\Desktop"]];
```

Then one that allows me to simply export every plot that I output:

```
Export["out.png", Out[-1]];
```

The problem in your exporting function is that you are not setting the directory for the figure correctly. Have a look into the exporting directory information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/AuthorTools/PaletteInterface/ExportCells/SpecifyingTheExportDirectory.html) and, if you want to avoid doing what I suggested above, use `FileNameJoin` ([example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportAndExportImages.html)).

EDIT: I didn't see this, but @b.gatessucks had suggested `FileNameJoin` before I did.